# PHP Date Conversion to Timestamp

Tags: php

I am trying to convert the following string (or strings of this time) to timestamps:

```
Closing date: 02 Apr 15

Closing date: 06 May 15
```

My code is as follows:

```
$start_date = explode("Closing date: ", $string);
                $start_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('DD M yy', $start_date[1]);
```

But when I try echoing $start_date->getTimestamp() it tells me

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getTimestamp() on a non-object
```

Any idea on what I may be doing wrong? DD M yy seems like the right date format to use.

Comment: Why don't you just use `strtotime`?

Comment: Why assume "seems" when you could just RTFM? http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php  you're making up your own format strings...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
$start_date = explode("Closing date: ", $string);
$start_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d M y', $start_date[1]);
```

The format you need to pass to `DateTime::createFromFormat()` to help it parse your data is `d M y`. I extracted the significance of the letters from the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php):

- `d` and `j`: Day of the month, 2 digits with or without leading zeros (`01` to `31` or `1` to `31`);
- `F` and `M`: A textual representation of a month, such as January or Sept (`January` through `December` or `Jan` through `Dec`);
- `y`: A two digit representation of a year (which is assumed to be in the range `1970-2069`, inclusive); Examples: `99` or `03` (which will be interpreted as `1999` and `2003`, respectively).

Comment: Very well explained! :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to change 'DD M yy' a to a right date format "d M y"

```
$start_date = explode("Closing date: ", 'Closing date: 02 Apr 15');
$start_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d M y', $start_date[1]);

     var_dump($start_date)

    object(DateTime)[3430]
      public 'date' => string '2015-04-02 15:27:28.000000' (length=26)
      public 'timezone_type' => int 3
      public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/London' (length=13)
```

Answer (score 1):

`DD M yy` is actually not the right format. Taken from the [DateTime::createFromFormat](https://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) docs:

> D and l -     A textual representation of a day - Mon through Sun or Sunday
>   through Saturday

Try doing a `var_dump` of `$start_date` before calling `getTimestamp`, I bet is's actually `false`:

> Returns a new DateTime instance or FALSE on failure.

The format you need to use is `d M y`.

Comment: DD "0" [0-9] | [1-2][0-9] | "3" [01] "07", "31"

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply convert date to `timestamps` format using `strtotime`

```
$string="Closing date: 02 Apr 15";
$start_date = explode("Closing date: ", $string);
print strtotime($start_date[1]);
```